# python - how to format socket recv() output?

Tags: python, sockets, recv

**Hi**,

this function prints output of socket recv(). In my code, socket connects to the Samsung TV.

```
def connection_status(self):

        connection_status = sock.recv(64)
        label_connection_status = "Status: ", connection_status

        label_connection_status = Label(self.master, text= label_connection_status)
        label_connection_status.grid(row=7, column=3, columnspan=4, padx=(15,0), ipady=8, sticky=W)
```

The label gives me this:[image: Screenshot of label]

With `print("Status: ", connection_status)` i getting this: `('Status: ', '\x00\x0c\x00iapp.samsung\x04\x00d\x00\x01\x00')`

And with `print(label_connection_status)` i getting this: `.139719774023552`

My questions are:

1. How to format the ouput and why is output of `print(label_connection_status)` `.139719774023552`??
2. I want to write "Status: Connected" in label if recv() returns something and "Status: Disconnected" if recv() returns "" (dont return anythink)
3. I want to update the connection state with recv() every 1 second

Please help me! And sorry for my bad english.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As for the second and third questions you could do something like:
    sock.settimeout(1)

```
try:
    data = sock.recv(64)
    print 'Status: Connected'
except socket.timeout:
    data = ''
    print 'Statuc: Disconnected'
```

In which you set the timeout to 1 second and if the connection times out it will print disconnected.

As for the label, the label is from Tkinter right? If I remember correctly that number represents your tkinter window (each window and children of the window get numbers to represent them to the operating system). I don't remember exactly how that works but I'm pretty sure that's what you got. If you want the text of the label you should use label_name["text"] or label_name.cget("text").

To answer your followup questions, here is the code, put this section in your **init** function

```
#Code to put in your __init__ function
self.connection_label = Label(self.master, text= '')
self.connection_label.grid(row=7, column=3, columnspan=4, padx=(15,0), ipady=8, sticky=W)
self.sock = socket.socket()
self.sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5555))
self.sock.settimeout(1)
```

(don't forget to change its ip and port)
and here is the function you need:

```
def connection_status(self):
    try:
        data = self.sock.recv(64)
        self.connection_label['text'] = 'Status: Connected'
    except socket.timeout:
        data = ''
        self.connection_label['text'] = 'Status: Disconnected'
    #This makes the program call this every 1000 milliseconds
    self.master.after(1000, self.connection_status, self.master)
```

The line at the bottom makes the program call that function every x milliseconds which is in this case 1000 so 1 second. Also don't forger to actually call the function connection_status in your init function.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I getting this error:
    except socket.timeout:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I have it in def. And yes, the label is from Tkinter

Comment: And how to write the updated status to the Tk label?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the syntax error comes from the fact that I used python2 print command instead of print(), you should try that. As for the update the label, just do what you did, it should work.

Comment: No, its not from print(). I post it now to answers

Comment: Your tabs don't match, you must remove a tab from connection_status = "" and print("Status: Disconnected").

Comment: Still dont working, same error, SyntaxErorr: invalid syntax on excep**t**

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid, I wrote sock.timeout instead of socket.timeout. I can't believe it took me so long to notice...

Comment: I gow it finaly to work! But the status of connection is not updating, i shut down the server and still only getting Status: Connected...

Comment: Save the label as self.connection_label and use something like self.connection_label['text'] = 'new text', what you now have is creating a new label everytime.

Comment: OK, but please write the code to your answer, im beginer in python

Comment: except sock.timeout: still not working, except socket.timeout: dont working too

Comment: For me function except sock.timeout: still dont working; i shut down the server and nothing happens, any error message sock is disconnected, nothink. And when I trying to reconnect, i get error "Is alredy connected...". Its really weird...

Comment: Check if you have sock.timeout or socket.timeout it needs to be socket.timeout

Comment: i tryied use both; except is not working. but if I shut down server, socket is still working and im able so send keys to server when is powered off. please help me is really weird

Comment: What is the exact error you get when using sokcet.timeout ? sock.timeout is a mistake and doesn't do anything.

Comment: i dont getting any error, simply it dowsnt work. socket.timeout dont recognize when socket disconnected, most likely its alive, but when i shut down the server, its still alive!! :(